# Port Forwarding by Using “HNetCfg.NATUPnP” Ole Object Failed - It was working before

Tags: delphi, upnp

I read the following question:
[Port Forwarding by Using "HNetCfg.NATUPnP" Ole Object Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805067/port-forwarding-by-using-hnetcfg-natupnp-ole-object-failed)

Used that example and worked successfully on windows xp sp3. Delphi Xe2. I could route and external port to my pc and worked just fine in everything.

After some days of work, this code stopped working:

Ports := Nat.StaticPortMappingCollection;

Ports is now getting NIL.

In the same network, the same code works in a windows 7. I do not have other windows xp for testing.

Seems that something changed, and seems to be in the environment. My windows xp is a virtual box session. The host is a windows 7 were the same code is still working. I have not noticed any change on virtual box params, no software update.

I am looking for guidance where to look for.